# Tweepy Stream doesn't connect

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy

I want to create a Twitter-Bot in Python with Tweepy for a school-project. I'm using the v2 Twitter API and the latest Tweepy update 4.13.0.
My problem:
I already got the bot to work a few times, but wanted to change the streaming rules again. So I deleted the old ones and added new ones. Since then the bot does not work anymore.
Every time I start my bot it does absolutely nothing. The rule should look like this, that all tweets have both keywords "Lügenpresse" and "Deutschland" and only German tweets are outputted.

```
from email.utils import localtime 
import time
import random 
import tweepy

api_key = "..."
api_secret = "..."
bearer_token = r"..."
access_token = "..."
access_token_secret = "..."

client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token, api_key, api_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)

auth = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler(api_key, api_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)


#Anweisungen was gestreamt werden soll
class MyStream(tweepy.StreamingClient): 
    def on_tweet(self, tweet):
        print(tweet.text) 
        try:
            client.like(tweet.id) 
            client.retweet(tweet.id) 
        except Exception as error:
            print(error)
        
        time.sleep(1) 


stream = MyStream(bearer_token=bearer_token)
rule = tweepy.StreamRule("(Lügenpresse AND Deutschland) (lang:de)")
stream.add_rules(rule)
stream.filter()
print("connected")
```

Comment: What happens when run you this script?

Comment: Nothing. It seems like it's just loading.

Comment: I can't help with the details of this, but it's often a good idea to strip back your code to simplify it and then go from there. It might be an idea to remove the class for starters, and just run it as a function to begin with.